# Is it possible to copy a text range (selected by script) in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I try in the script I write, select a text range from a text frame the user has selected, and copy the selection of text range to the clipboard:

```
var userSelection = activeDocument.selection;
userSelection[0].textRange.lines[0].select();
app.copy();
```

When I run the code above, the following error message pops up:

[image: error copy selected text range by script]

And when I confirm the error message and stop the script operation and return to Illustrator, it seems the script selected the text range without going into text editing mode:

[image: text range selected by script looks]

And when I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (on mac) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, the same error message above pops up.

So what I realized is that you probably can't copy text range without going into text editing mode.

Is there a way to enter text editing mode and thus copy text range, or is there another way to copy text range?

Comment: What's you end goal? Do you need to insert the text in another application?

Comment: In fact, the ultimate goal is to paste the text range into another text frame so that all character attributes are transferred to the new text frame. And I understand that this paste can only be done in text editing mode. So maybe I should ask "How do I **paste** a text range into a text frame?", But it probably doesn't matter. In the end, what I want to know is how to get the text into text editing mode to do this, or there might be another way to paste a text range into a text frame.

Comment: That's precisely why I am asking. Because if you want to move the text within Illustrator you should avoid to use the `copy()` and `paste()` methods, as there are dedicated methods to move text around that don't require the clipboard. Will post my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving text from one text frame to another with all its character attributes intact can be done be using the line object's `duplicate()` method, to duplicate the line into the target text frame. See this little sample snippet:

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var sourceFrame = doc.textFrames.getByName("source");
var targetFrame = doc.textFrames.getByName("target");

var line = sourceFrame.textRange.lines[0];

line.duplicate(targetFrame);
```